# How would I connect to an sFTP server from terminus

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, remote-connection

I am using [terminus](https://termius.com/) premium(I have the student subscription) on Debian Linux and I want to connect to an FTP server. How would I go about setting this up? I have tested this using another FTP client on the same network and computer and it succeeded.

Comment: FTP server, FTPS server, or SFTP server? Completely different things.

Comment: @grawity it is a SFTP server

Comment: https://docs.termius.com/termius-handbook/sftp

Comment: @ssnobody I tried that

Comment: What problem did you have trying to follow the handbook?

Comment: well, it says to set up the host, but when I try to set t up, there is no space for sftp login details @ssnobody

Comment: Did you add a host as specified? https://docs.termius.com/termius-handbook/hosts#add-a-host Is the username and password field missing from the Add host dialog? On the phone version, it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/i529m

Comment: @ssnobody where would I input a password? I saw a field for a username and filled that incorrectly, but there is no password field

Comment: Care to provide a screenshot of your add host screen? There should be a password field there.

Answer (score 0):

First add the new host and if available, connect via ssh, then it will be listed in the right side instead of default empty state pic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).